# if else angular ng-class not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this is in my `ng-repeat`, so I want if lp-image is not zero, apply class col-md-8 and else apply col-md-12 if it's zero. The result is strange, it returned col-md-12.

```
ng-class="{'col-md-8':item.lp-image != 0, 'col-md-12':item.lp-image == 0}">
```

Comment: Show your controller code? What is item here?

Comment: @JayShukla there is no problem with the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ng-class="{'col-md-8':item['lp-image'] != 0, 'col-md-12':item['lp-image'] == 0}">
```

Comment: @user3346088 Changed `item.lp-image` to `item['lp-image']`

Comment: @user3346088 Hyphens aren't allowed in identifiers. Your code is attempting subtraction -- `item.lp - image`.

Comment: ops, it doesn't.. it only apply col-md-8

Comment: Yes, As Jonathan said. that was the problem but you can still access it like this. Though, you should follow javascript standards.

Comment: {{item['lp']}} print like this and see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable name cannot contain a hyphen `-`, it's parsed as a minus operator. Use JavaScript's naming convention of camelCase, i.e. `item.lpImage`.

Comment: @SamV You're joking, right? Why change keys when it's nowhere near necessary?